# Create a POST service in app engine with python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am very new to app engine and python too so this might sound like a very basic question. I want to create a RESTful service which handles POST requests(using Python, app engine)

For Example:

```
www.myproject.appspot.com - is my URL
```

and if I do a simple GET call to this(from a browser or REST client etc), it returns what ever is in the code, like here it is >Hello!<

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    self.response.write("Hello!")
```

What I want to do is make it a POST request, like if I hit it with some JSON like

```
 {"myName" : NameString}
```

It will print the name in NameString. I know this sounds like a very silly question but please bear with me as my internet search has left me confused with which method to use some have suggested using EndPoints API, Django etc. But I believe my requirement is very basic and webapp2 can handle it.

I just want so direction or basic examples to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the way to get the [POST data](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html?highlight=url#post-data) from the request into the response:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        name = self.request.POST['myName']
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write("Hello, %s!" % name)
```

Comment: Hey Thanks! but i had to tweak this code a bit to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Write a method that will handle the POST method and set proper content type:

https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html#http-methods-translated-to-class-methods

In your case it would be:

```
import json
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    name = 'John Snow'
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    self.response.write(json.dumps({"myName" : name}))
```

Comment: Hey GOT fan..thanks, I had something different in mind but the link u have given is very useful